# in python how to remove this \n from string or list

Tags: python, string

this is my main  string

```
"action","employee_id","name"
"absent","pritesh",2010/09/15 00:00:00
```

so after name coolumn its goes to new line but here i append to list  a new line character is added and make it like this way

data_list***** `['"action","employee_id","name"\n"absent","pritesh",2010/09/15 00:00:00\n']`

here its append the new line character with absent but actually its a new line strarting but its appended i want to make it like

data_list***** `['"action","employee_id","name","absent","pritesh",2010/09/15 00:00:00']`

Comment: I don't understand the syntax you are using. What's with all the asterisks?

Comment: Maybe you wanted too use http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Answer (score 9):

Davide's answer can be written even simpler as:

```
data_list = [word.strip() for word in data_list]
```

But I'm not sure it's what you want. Please write some sample in python.

Comment: with strip you get also rid of the '\r'

Answer (score 8):

```
replaces = inString.replace("\n", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you can use `strip()` to get rid of `'\n'`:

```
>>> data = line.strip().split(',')
```

Secondly, you may want to use the csv module to do that:

```
>>> import csv
>>> f = open("test")
>>> r = csv.reader(f)
>>> print(r.next())
['action', 'employee_id', 'name']
```

Comment: Your suggestion to use the csv module is definitely the way to go. However, if using `strip()` then you may want to consider stripping only the `'\n'` and preserve any whitespace that may precede it, I would suggest using `line.rstrip('\n')` which will remove just the newline from the end of the line, rather than using `strip()` which will remove all whitespace from both ends of the line which may not be desirable in cases where a free-form text column appears as the first or last column.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do like that:

```
in_string.replace('\n', ',', 1).split(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(word):
    return word.strip()
data_list = map(f, data_list)
```

Comment: Yes, I did :) Edited accordingly :)