# Python remove tabs and carriage lines from unicode list

Tags: python, unicode, str-replace

I've looked at previous answers to this ([python how to remove this n from string or list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903523/in-python-how-to-remove-this-n-from-string-or-list), [remove a list item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347063/remove-a-n-list-item-from-a-python-list) and [python remove whitespace in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/python-remove-whitespaces-in-string)) but can't get the solutions to work.

I have a list with a single element like so:

```
list = [u'\r\n\r\n\r\n            \r\n                \r\n                    \r\n                    123 Main St., Peoria\r\n                \r\n\r\n            \r\n             |\r\n             \r\n                    \r\n                        \r\n                            \r\n                            123-456-789\r\n                        \r\n                    \r\n            \r\n        ']
```

It has an address and a phone number and what I'd like is just to have this returned is:

```
123 Main St., Peoria;123-456-789
```

I've tried stuff like:

```
str(list).strip(' \r\n\t')
```

and

```
str(list).replace('\r','')
```

But they don't work, so I'm thinking maybe it's a unicode issue? How do I get around it?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it masks the build-in type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

li = [u'\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n 123 Main St., Peoria\r\n \r\n\r\n \r\n |\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n 123-456-789\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n ']
print re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', li[0].replace(' |', ';'))
```

prints

```
123 Main St., Peoria; 123-456-789
```

Answer (score 5):

Just take the *one* element out of the list and replace on there:

```
print lst[0].replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')
```

There is no need to convert the list itself to string here.

You could, in this case, also combine `unicode.strip` with a `.splitlines()` to remove whitespace from each line, then rejoin:

```
print u' '.join([l.strip() for l in lst[0].splitlines() if l.strip()])
```

This prints:

```
123 Main St., Peoria | 123-456-789
```